# how to configure debezium fields sent on update events (mongo connector)

Tags: mongodb, debezium

I want to use debezium mongo connector to:

-> get events from mongo

-> get them in my kafka

-> read from kafka

my issue is, when debezium gets update events from mongo it only sends the updated fields:

> The value of an update change event on this collection will actually
>   have the exact same schema, and its payload will be structured the
>   same but will hold different values. Specifically, an update event
>   will not have an after value and will instead have a patch string
>   containing the JSON representation of the idempotent update operation.

and I was wondering if i can configure it somehow cause there are some fields I would like to get with the updates events.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to solve the problem using Kafka Streams - in a similar (simplified) way as in this case https://debezium.io/blog/2018/03/08/creating-ddd-aggregates-with-debezium-and-kafka-streams/