# kafka connector debezium mongodb CDC update/$set message without filter(_id value)

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, mongodb-oplog

i am trying to setup syncing from mongodb to kudu with debezium mongodb connector. but as debezium doc tell and also i tried by myself and found, there are no filter(_id value) for debezium mongodb CDC update/$set message.

```
{
    "after": null,
    "patch": "{\"$v\" : 1,\"$set\" : {\"_upts_ratio_average_points\" : {\"$numberLong\" : \"1564645156749\"},\"updatets\" : {\"$numberLong\" : \"1564645156749\"}}}",
    "source": {
        "version": "0.9.5.Final",
        "connector": "mongodb",
        "name": "promongodbdeb05",
        "rs": "mgset-13056897",
        "ns": "strtest.mg_jsd_result_all",
        "sec": 1564645156,
        "ord": 855,
        "h": -1570214265415439167,
        "initsync": false
    },
    "op": "u",
    "ts_ms": 1564648181536
}
```

I don't understand why designed like this, without filter really no idea which document is updated. I downloaded the source code of this connector and try to fix it. It looks like class `io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope` is where MongoDB op log message is extracted with code like these. And this file is with confusing both `_id` and `id` manipulations and it looks like the committer of the connector indeed tried to include `_id` value in the CDC update message. I tried to change `valueDocument.append("id", keyDocument.get("id"));` to `valueDocument.append("id", keyDocument.get("_id"));` still no `_id` value in CDC message after the connector is rebuilt and deployed.

Anyone familiar with debezium can help me with this?

```
{
    private BsonDocument getUpdateDocument(R patchRecord, BsonDocument keyDocument) {
        BsonDocument valueDocument = new BsonDocument();
        BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.parse(patchRecord.value().toString());

        if (document.containsKey("$set")) {
            valueDocument = document.getDocument("$set");
        }

        if (document.containsKey("$unset")) {
            Set<Entry<String, BsonValue>> unsetDocumentEntry = document.getDocument("$unset").entrySet();

            for (Entry<String, BsonValue> valueEntry : unsetDocumentEntry) {
                // In case unset of a key is false we don't have to do anything with it,
                // if it's true we want to set the value to null
                if (!valueEntry.getValue().asBoolean().getValue()) {
                    continue;
                }
                valueDocument.append(valueEntry.getKey(), new BsonNull());
            }
        }

        if (!document.containsKey("$set") && !document.containsKey("$unset")) {
            if (!document.containsKey("_id")) {
                throw new ConnectException("Unable to process Mongo Operation, a '$set' or '$unset' is necessary " +
                        "for partial updates or '_id' is expected for full Document replaces.");
            }
            // In case of a full update we can use the whole Document as it is
            // see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#replace-a-document-entirely
            valueDocument = document;
            valueDocument.remove("_id");
        }

        if (!valueDocument.containsKey("id")) {
            valueDocument.append("id", keyDocument.get("id"));
        }

        if (flattenStruct) {
            final BsonDocument newDocument = new BsonDocument();
            valueDocument.forEach((fKey, fValue) -> newDocument.put(fKey.replace(".", delimiter), fValue));
            valueDocument = newDocument;
        }

        return valueDocument;
    }

}
```

@jiri, thanks a lot for your reply, the message i got always like this:

```
{ "after": null, "patch": "{\"$v\" : 1,\"$set\" : {\"_upts_ratio_average_points\" : {\"$numberLong\" : \"1564645156749\"},\"updatets\" : {\"$numberLong\" : \"1564645156749\"}}}", "source": { "version": "0.9.5.Final", "connector": "mongodb", "name": "promongodbdeb05", "rs": "mgset-13056897", "ns": "strtest.mg_jsd_result_all", "sec": 1564645156, "ord": 855, "h": -1570214265415439167, "initsync": false }, "op": "u", "ts_ms": 1564648181536 }
```

and i searched and found someone else can get debezium mongodb CDC like this article:
https://rmoff.net/2018/03/27/streaming-data-from-mongodb-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/
like this:
{
  "after": {\"_id\" : {\"$oid\" : \"58385328e4b001431e4e497a\"}, ....

One can see I can't get `_id`, so no way for me know this change on which document/record, but as to the above post, it looks like the author can get `_id`, also by checking code, `_id` should be there. I used both `0.9.5Final` and the `0.7.4 rev` which used in the above post. both no luck for me, always without _id value.

Comment: Hi, could you please ad an example of the message how it looks like now and compare it side by side with an example how would you need to look it?

Comment: @jiri, my comment is long, so posted in questions. your help is really appreciated, and also in debezium official doc, also without _id like this. but as the post i found and the source code i checked, _id should be there, really confusing for me. : {
    "schema": { ... },
    "payload": {
      "op": "u",
      "ts_ms": 1465491461815,
      "patch": "{\"$set\":{\"first_name\":\"Anne Marie\"}}",

Comment: official update CDC example you can find in https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/

Comment: found another stackoverflow post asked exactly same questions as mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911479/how-to-configure-debezium-fields-sent-on-update-events-mongo-connector

Comment: Have you correctly configured SMT on the source connector?

Comment: hi Jiri, after i added "SMT", now i got id. One more question can you pls. help with, who can I get mongodb CDC message with the whole document when the CDC happens? For mysql  always the whole record can be in CDC , which is convenient for flink or other streaming app to count/sum based on the whole record information.

Comment: @Jiri, found in manual "The UnwrapFromEnvelope SMT will by default filter out both delete and tombstone records, though you can change this if you’re using the SMT and want to keep one or both of these kinds of messages.",  need a way to both use SMT and to have delete CDC msg? no details found to do both in manul. BTW, i used "transforms": "unwrap", "transforms.unwrap.type":  "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope",

Comment: Please check delete.handling.mode and drop.tombstones of the unwrap envelope.
The aggregated state in the update message is a little bit sad story - you need to use Kafka Streams to keep the existing state and apply it on top of it. We ar eplanning to make an example for that but we did not get into it yet.
You'd need to use a KTable to store the event state and merge the update messages with it to get the aggregated value.

Comment: really appreciate your feedback jiri, i added "delete.handling.mode" : "rewrite", but still no message for my mongodb remove op, anything wrong?

Answer (score -2):

when consumer the topic,need to add `--property key.print=true`.It will have the Key.The value is in the key part.Thanks