# received odd kafka message from debezium mongodb connector

Tags: mongodb, confluent-platform, connector, debezium

I used the titled connector, usually create/update/delete message can be received as described by the official manual.

But I got a message like this:

```
{
    "_id": "8762506_911", 
    "$v": 1, 
    "$set": {
        "users_count": {
            "dollar number Long": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't match to the description in manual, looks like an internal log relevant to one of my update to the document.

Anyone can tell me how to block these kinds of the message sent out by the connector? (BTW, the dollar number Long is trimmed as prevented posted directly somehow in this website)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305162/kafka-connector-debezium-mongodb-cdc-update-set-message-without-filter-id-valu
I want to know how you solve this problem

Comment: check key part of kafka message

Comment: never mind, my mistake not reading debezium mongodb manual carefully, not an issue